# How to extract a floating number from a string and add it using simple operation on python

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x

I have a file named ping.txt which has the values that shows the time taken to ping an ip for n number of times.
I have my ping.txt contains:

```
time=35.9
time=32.4
```

I have written a python code to extract this floating number alone and add it using regular expression. But I feel that the below code is the indirect way of completing my task. The findall regex I am using here outputs a list which is them converted, join and then added.

```
import re
add,tmp=0,0
with open("ping.txt","r+") as pingfile:
        for i in pingfile.readlines():
                tmp=re.findall(r'\d+\.\d+',i)
                add=add+float("".join(tmp))

        print("The sum of the times is :",add)
```

My question is how to solve this problem without using regex or any other way to reduce the number of lines in my code to make it more efficient?
In other words, can I use different regex or some other method to do this operation?
~

Comment: You could use csv and set the delimiter to `=`. I can't decide if that would be silly or not.

Comment: Yes. That is silly if I add the numbers in csv file. But storing these numbers in a csv file and then add it using python code make it complex. My aim is to use different regex or some other simple code to execute the above task in python itself instead of creating extra .csv file

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the following:

```
with open('ping.txt', 'r') as f:
    s = sum(float(line.split('=')[1]) for line in f)
```

**Output:**

```
>>> with open('ping.txt', 'r') as f:
...     s = sum(float(line.split('=')[1]) for line in f)
...
>>> s
68.3
```

**Note:** I assume each line of your file contains `time=some_float_number`

Answer (score 1):

You could do it like this:

```
import re
total = sum(float(s) for s in re.findall(r'\d+(\.\d+)?', open("ping.txt","r+").read()))
```

Comment: Thank you sir! I feel your code is still written in a complex way though you have made it in couple of lines

Answer (score 1):

If you have the string:

```
>>> s='time=35.9'
```

Then to get the value, you just need:

```
>>> float(s.split('=')[1]))
35.9
```

You don't need regular expressions for something with a simple delimiter.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the string split to split each line at `'='` and append them to a list. At the end, you can simply call the `sum` function to print the sum of elements in the list

```
temp = []
with open("test.txt","r+") as pingfile:
    for i in pingfile.readlines():
        temp.append(float(str.split(i,'=')[1]))       

    print("The sum of the times is :",sum(temp))
```

Answer (score 0):

Use This in RE

```
tmp = re.findall("[0-9]+.[0-9]+",i)
```

After that run a loop

```
sum = 0
for each in tmp:
    sum = sum + float(each)
```